# Item count descriptive statistics

Tags: r, summary

I have a data frame

```
x  userId  bookId  rating
1       1     412       6
2       1     454       5
3       2     412       4
```

etc..

Basically, a user has rated many books, and a book has many ratings.

I need to extract some descriptive statistics around `userId`. Average amount of ratings given, average rating given etc.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have a look at `help("aggregate")`.

Comment: Or try `mutate` from `dplyr`

Comment: or try to search for summarizing with `data.table` package on SO ... `library(data.table);setDT(df)[,list(avAmount=length(unique(bookID)), avRating=mean(rating)),userID]`

Comment: @DatamineR `dplyr::mutate` does nothing more than just `"$<-"`. It's like saying "Try using R"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do those computations with `data.table`:

If your `data.frame` is called `books`:

```
require(data.table)
setDT(books)

# average rating by user
books[, mean(rating), by=userId]
#   userId  V1
#1:      1 5.5
#2:      2 4.0

# average amount of ratings given :
books[, .N, by=userId][, mean(N)]
#[1] 1.5
```

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure that I get your exact question/task. But the following could offer some insight:

```
data = read.table(header = T, stringsAsFactors = F,  text  = "x  userId  bookId  rating
1       1     412       6
2       1     454       5
3       2     412       4")

# Number of ratings per user 
userFreq = data.frame(table(data$userId)) 
# Var1 Freq
# 1    1    2
# 2    2    1

# mean rating per userID
meanRatingPerUser = aggregate(data$rating, by=list(data$userId), FUN = mean )     
# Group.1   x
# 1       1 5.5
# 2       2 4.0

# mean rating per book
meanRatingPerBook = aggregate(data$rating, by=list(data$bookId), FUN = mean )   
# Group.1 x
# 1     412 5
# 2     454 5


# "Summary" function, applied per bookID
moreStats = aggregate(data$rating, by=list(data$bookId), FUN = summary ) 
# Group.1 x.Min. x.1st Qu. x.Median x.Mean x.3rd Qu. x.Max.
# 1     412    4.0       4.5      5.0    5.0       5.5    6.0
# 2     454    5.0       5.0      5.0    5.0       5.0    5.0
```